# Does Greg Rahn's "join order benchmark" reflect real world OLAP join scenarios?

Tags: query-performance, join, benchmark

Greg Rahn's ["join order benchmark"](https://github.com/gregrahn/join-order-benchmark) has dozens of inner join queries on the IMDB database.

Does this benchmark and the database itself reflect common real world OLAP join scenarios? How does a join optimizer's performance on these benchmark correlate to general join performance for the real world?

For example:

```
SELECT MIN(cn.name) AS movie_company,
   MIN(mi_idx.info) AS rating,
   MIN(t.title) AS complete_euro_dark_movie
FROM complete_cast AS cc,
 comp_cast_type AS cct1,
 comp_cast_type AS cct2,
 company_name AS cn,
 company_type AS ct,
 info_type AS it1,
 info_type AS it2,
 keyword AS k,
 kind_type AS kt,
 movie_companies AS mc,
 movie_info AS mi,
 movie_info_idx AS mi_idx,
 movie_keyword AS mk,
 title AS t
WHERE cct1.kind = 'crew'
  AND cct2.kind != 'complete+verified'
  AND cn.country_code != '[us]'
  AND it1.info = 'countries'
  AND it2.info = 'rating'
  AND k.keyword IN ('murder',
                'murder-in-title',
                'blood',
                'violence')
  AND kt.kind IN ('movie',
              'episode')
  AND mc.note NOT LIKE '%(USA)%'
  AND mc.note LIKE '%(200%)%'
  AND mi.info IN ('Sweden',
              'Norway',
              'Germany',
              'Denmark',
              'Swedish',
              'Danish',
              'Norwegian',
              'German',
              'USA',
              'American')
  AND mi_idx.info < '8.5'
  AND t.production_year > 2000
  AND kt.id = t.kind_id
  AND t.id = mi.movie_id
  AND t.id = mk.movie_id
  AND t.id = mi_idx.movie_id
  AND t.id = mc.movie_id
  AND t.id = cc.movie_id
  AND mk.movie_id = mi.movie_id
  AND mk.movie_id = mi_idx.movie_id
  AND mk.movie_id = mc.movie_id
  AND mk.movie_id = cc.movie_id
  AND mi.movie_id = mi_idx.movie_id
  AND mi.movie_id = mc.movie_id
  AND mi.movie_id = cc.movie_id
  AND mc.movie_id = mi_idx.movie_id
  AND mc.movie_id = cc.movie_id
  AND mi_idx.movie_id = cc.movie_id
  AND k.id = mk.keyword_id
  AND it1.id = mi.info_type_id
  AND it2.id = mi_idx.info_type_id
  AND ct.id = mc.company_type_id
  AND cn.id = mc.company_id
  AND cct1.id = cc.subject_id
  AND cct2.id = cc.status_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who Greg Rahn is, but that's one ugly query, especially with the stuffing of the predicates of the `JOIN`s into the `WHERE` clause instead of on a proper `JOIN` clause between each referenced object. That's a non-standard syntax, and I recommend not following it.

Order of the objects being `JOIN`ed depends on the database system we're talking about. Some do explicitly care about the order of the tables (I believe generally by the cardinality of the data set of that object) in order to achieve the most optimal plan but most don't care and automatically try to optimize the `JOIN` order themselves, such as Microsoft SQL Server.

Of course the complexity of parsing, analyzing, and determining the best execution plan for a query increases with the more tables that are being joined together. For example, with 3 tables there's 6 ways to order the tables and `JOIN` them:

```
1. A-B-C
2. A-C-B
3. B-A-C
4. B-C-A
5. C-A-B
6. C-B-A
```

And in Microsoft SQL Server, there are 3 types of `JOIN` operators it can use for any given `JOIN`: Nested Loops, Hash Match, Merge Join. So with only 3 tables there's actually 18 unique ways to `JOIN` all the data together then. That's 18 unique execution plans the optimizer needs to analyze and choose the best one from, in a very minimal amount of time. So you can imagine how quickly that number grows when you add a fourth or fifth table to `JOIN` to, where 15 tables is some number in the billions (maybe more?) execution plans.

Because of the vast number of execution plans the optimizer needs to choose from and because the slightest change in a query in Microsoft SQL Server results in a new plan being recalculated, re-arranging the order of the tables being `JOIN`ed *could* result in a more optimal plan but just as well could result in a less optimal one too. Again because Microsoft SQL Server doesn't care about the order of the tables per se, rather it does the re-ordering for you under the hood, and it's essentially sheer luck at that point that you've caused a different execution plan to be generated. Though most times you'll likely see the same plan anyway. This is probably true for most database systems that optimize the `JOIN` order for you.

Comment: "stuffing of the predicates of the JOINs into the WHERE clause": if you think of it another way, this grammar makes sense. `SELECT {columns} from A,B,C where {conditions}`: let ⊗ denote cross product, the query means projecting (the subset of A⊗B⊗C that satisfy {conditions}) onto {columns}. It's a very regular generate-and-filter, semantically equivalent to `SELECT {columns} from A join B join C on {conditions}`

Comment: @larryliu I didn't say it doesn't make sense, I just said it's non-standard, and hurts readability (at least believed by most developers). You won't normally see that syntax in the wild. Regardless, that's irrelevant to the performance aspect (for the most part) of your question. I just wanted to point it out as an FYI, in case you wanted to follow standard syntax in your own queries.